# Uploading python functions to aws lambda

Tags: python, git, bash, aws-lambda

I've developed two AWS lambda python functions.
As we all need source-control I am saving my project in git. 
The question is what is the best way to update AWS lambda with updates from git. 
AFAIK currently the only way is to use aws cli with update-function-code. 
I wrote the following bash to manually update the code:

```py
#!/bin/bash
command -v aws >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "This command requires aws but it's not installed or not in the path.  Aborting."; exit 1; }
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

if [ "$#" -ne 2 -a "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <code file path> [lambda function name if not same]"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [ -e $1 ]; then
    echo "File $1 does not exist"
    exit 1
fi

ZIPFILE="lamzip.zip"
LAMBDA_FUNC="lambda_function.py"

if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    AWS_LAMBDA_NAME=$(basename $1)
    AWS_LAMBDA_NAME="${AWS_LAMBDA_NAME%.*}"
else
    AWS_LAMBDA_NAME=$2
fi

echo "Will upload your code file to aws lamda ${bold}$AWS_LAMBDA_NAME${normal}"

cp -f $1 /tmp/$LAMBDA_FUNC
rm -f /tmp/$ZIPFILE
zip -j /tmp/$ZIPFILE  /tmp/$LAMBDA_FUNC

CMD="aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $AWS_LAMBDA_NAME --zip-file fileb:///tmp/$ZIPFILE --publish"
echo executing: $CMD
$CMD

exit 0
```

Would I have jenkins or similar I could automate this script.

But is there some better way out there?

**EDIT** 28/1/16 updated to the script I am using now it assumes the script name is the method name in aws unless provided another parameter

Answer (score 0):

Using a build server is a normal way to deploy AWS lambda functions, it is really as simple as you are doing it. We have been using a very similar approach and it is going well.